# Merge raster layer error, illegal size

Tags: qgis, dem, mosaic, gdal-merge, error-1

I have an issue with merging several tiles. I am loading the original XYZ files into QGIS (works fine) and try to merge them afterwards yia `Raster/miscellaneous/merge` . If I only merge 2 tiles this works without any problem but as soon as I try to merge more than 2 tiles at once I get :

```
GDAL-Befehl:
gdal_merge.bat -ot Float32 -of GTiff -o "C:/Users/Jonas Wischnewski/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ITBVYL/4c383c33f450475aa0b8886a7f7a8c2a/OUTPUT.tif" --optfile "C:/Users/Jonas Wischnewski/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ITBVYL/4c6ee11824de43f9ab2d05a72c02f4b5/mergeInputFiles.txt"
GDAL-Befehlsausgaben:
**ERROR 1: Attempt to create 401x-1198 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.**
```

The XYZ Files don't have anything suspicious IMO:

```
362000.0 5814000.0 39.315 
362001.0 5814000.0 39.302
362002.0 5814000.0 39.304
...
```

Interestingly when I use other XYZ DEM Data from a different source with a similar input:

```
686000.00 5848000.00 33.59
686005.00 5848000.00 32.40
686010.00 5848000.00 33.69
...
```

this works perfectly fine.

Merging the rasters via Mosaic does work in this case, but it changes the z-values to an extend where it is not usable anymore for further processing.

Comment: Please provide some test data. The negative size of the raster means that in some place the max value of easting or northing is interpreted to be smaller than the minimum value.

Comment: The data originate from a official auhtority and can be downloaded at https://data.geobasis-bb.de/geobasis/daten/dgm/xyz/